# Measure on Boolean algebra

Tags: measure-theory, boolean-algebra

my question is:

> Suppose that $\mathfrak{B}$ is a measurable Boolean algebra, does this mean that "Every measure on $\mathfrak{B}$ should be strictly positive ? or this will be the case after QUOTIENTING it.

Please someone explain this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is a  measurable Boolean algebra?

Comment: I mean, we can define a measures on it.

Comment: If you mean simply a measurable space, the answer is clearly that you need to quotient out the ideal of null sets first.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be (temporarily) closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. Making these improvements will attract more appropriate answers and make the question more valuable for future MSE visitors.

Comment: Suppose we have an abstract Boolean algebra $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mu$ is a (finitely additive) measure on it. It is necessary that $\mu$ is strictly positive (finitely additive) measure.

Comment: Have you looked at measures on finite Boolean algebras or other atomic algebras?

Comment: I do not mean finite Boolean algebra, what I mean is finitely additive measure on Boolean algebra.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I am asking: have you looked at the special case where you also assume the Boolean algebra is finite. That is one path to find the answer to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I have not seen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not require that the measure be strictly positive, then every Boolean algebra admits a two valued measure (Boolean prime ideal theorem). Also not all Boolean algebras admit strictly positive measure. There is a nice characterization in an old paper of Kelly which you can access [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-9/issue-4/Measures-on-Boolean-algebras/pjm/1103038890.full).

Comment: Thanks alot for this reply.

Comment: I hope you find Kelly's paper useful - Let me know if you have questions about it. Some questions mentioned by Kelly in that paper have already been answered. And do not get discouraged by the cop attacks/downvotes.

Comment: I got it dear and I will try to read it, then I will ask you anything unclear to me.